# Some vertices stay in their position when rigged

Tags: objects, rigging, armature

I have a model which has been rigged for all of the body parts. However, the hair (which is a seperate model from the rest, meaning it can't be a mess up from that) has a couple vertices that decide to just stay there when animating my object. Here is an example of what it is doing:

[image: Hair vertices staying in position]

I have tried:

- Weight painting the hair

  - Makes her hair fall from her head at end of animation
- Making the model one whole mesh

  - Yields same results, no effect whatsoever

Sorry if this is a duplicate, the other questions' answers did no help, as seen by what I have tried.

Comment: I need help with this for a project, please answer.

Answer (score 2):

There are only two reasons that vertices don't follow the bone you expect them to.

- They aren't weighted to that bone
- They are ALSO weighted to ANOTHER bone

Not only do you need to make sure that those verts are weighted to the right bone, but you need to REMOVE them from any other bones. That's literally all there is to know about bones and weights.